# Powerline AV Compatibility With Gigabit Router (D-Link DHP-311AV and DHP-308AV)

Tags: router, gigabit-ethernet, powerline-networking

I'm now using an AC1900 Gigabit Router that came with the ISP for my FibreOptic connection. I have an existing DHP-311AV and DHP-308AV pair that I want to use to extend my network to "isolated" rooms however, when I connect my devices to the plugged AVs, I only get a self-assigned IP (`169.x.x.x`)--both wifi and ethernet.

This works with my old 100Mbps router (ASUS).

I tried resetting to factory defaults etc but I always get the same result. Has anyone else experience the same problem?

I got 2 options to move forward:

1. Call support - which I doubt will be fruitful.
2. Upgrade the firmware from the support website.

Comment: Sounds like your PowerLine adapters are having problems with Gigabit speeds, have you tried putting a 10/100 switch between the router and primary PowerLine adapter?

Comment: Hi @acejavelin, this was resolved by restarting the router---I don't know why it's needed. ***rolling eyes*** Thanks for helping out anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by restarting the router. ****Rolling eyes****

Once plugged in and paired, I was able to get a proper IP address from the router.